# Easiest way to get the value of a key in request.POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a user with a list of schools he has entered in his userprofile. I want to give him the ability to delete any one of his entries.

The following is the way I am currently using to delete a database entry, based upon the value of a key in the template:

```
# in template
{% for education in educations %}
    <p>{{ education.school }} 
    <input type="submit" name="delete_{{education.id}}" value="Delete" /></p>
{% endfor %}

# in view

if 'Delete' in request.POST.values():
    for key in request.POST.keys():
        if key.startswith('delete'):
            education_id = key[7:]
    profile.educations.remove(Education.objects.get(id=education_id))
```

Is there an easier way to get the value of a key, rather than having to iterate over `for key in request.POST.keys()`? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms are free. Make more of them.

```
{% for education in educations %}
     something something
     <form action="..." method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ education.id }}">
         <input type="submit" value="Delete">
     </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in the view:

```
id = request.POST['id']
profile.educations.remove(...)
```

Or put the id a GET parameter, instead of a hidden field (just make sure you don't use GET method for a form — those should never have any side effects).

Answer (score 0):

While I also agree that forms are nice, you can also simplify your code a bit:

```
if 'Delete' in request.POST.values():
    for key in request.POST.keys():
        if key.startswith('delete'):
            education_id = key[7:]
    profile.educations.remove(Education.objects.get(id=education_id))
```

Could be simplified into:

```
for education_id in [key[7:] for key, value in request.POST.iteritems() if value == 'Delete' and key.startswith('delete')]:
    profile.educations.remove(Education.objects.get(id=education_id))
```

I came up with another approach using the filter function but it was much messier and looked less elegant than the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'button_name' in request.POST.keys():
       do_something
elif other button name
```